# How does this mutual exclusion pseudocode work?

Tags: c

```
bool flag[2] = {false, false}
process p(i):   // i in { 0, 1 }
while (flag[1-i]) {
    // do nothing
}
flag[i] = true
while (flag[1-i]) {
    // do nothing
}
<critical section>
flag[i] = false
```

This code is make me crazy. It is a code built to solve mutual exclusion between the two programs (0 , 1). 
Can some one explain me how does the flag change for each program 0 and 1 when put into the code.

Comment: What is `1-i` in each case at each step?

Comment: So "i" will = 0 at first and at second step "i" equal 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array of 2 booleans, `flag`, must be in shared memory for this to have a chance of working.  For processes, that is crucial; if these were threads, you'd not need shared memory.

Initially, neither process 0 or 1 has set its `flag` value to `true`.

Suppose process `i = 0` tries to gain access to the critical section. The first busy loop (`while` loop) waits until `flag[1]` is `false` (and it is false at the moment); then the code sets `flag[0] = true`.  The code now enters the second busy loop; `flag[1]` is still `false`, so it goes ahead and enters the critical section safely, knowing that the other process is not in the critical section either.

Suppose that while process 0 is in the critical section, process 1 tries to enter it too.  It is blocked in the first busy loop because `flag[0]` is true.  It remains like that until process 0 leaves and sets `flag[0]` back to false.  When process 0 leaves, process 1 sets `flag[1]` to true, enters the second busy loop, and then leaves because `flag[0]` is false; it is now in the critical section.

Why the two busy loops?  Because it might happen that the two processes are running on multiple cores at the same time, and both might enter the first busy loop at the same time.  They would both see that the other's flag is false, exit the loop and set their own flag to true, and recheck that the other's is still false.  Most of the time, one of them would see that the other's is false and would enter the critical section.  Occasionally, they might both spot that the other's is true (because they were working so much in lock-step), and then both would enter the second busy-loop, and neither would exit — deadlock.

So, I'm not convinced that the code is a foolproof mutual exclusion mechanism, though it would require bad luck to get into deadlock.  However, given enough attempts, bad luck will occur — long-running processes can't afford the risk.